# WIX Custom Action running as 32 bit process

Tags: wix, wix3.6

I need to get my Custom Action to run as an x64 bit process and am using Visual Studio 2010. When i run the msi i see the following entry in the verbose log file:

Hello, I'm your 32bit Elevated custom action server

and the custom action fails due to wrong processor architecture (I am calling DISM.exe via a batch file). My project is fairly simple:

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" >
        <Component Id="Launch.cmd" Guid="{423CD408-F053-496B-8FA7-6C329A2F53BB}" Win64="yes">
            <File Id="Launch.cmd" Name="Launch.cmd" Source="C:\Temp\Build\MSU Wrapper for SCUP\Launch.cmd" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" ProcessorArchitecture="x64"/>
        </Component>
        <Component Id="KB977453.cab" Guid="{E8ABB2AE-6F57-4153-B44C-E1083D6702B1}" Win64="yes">
            <File Id="KB977453.cab" Name="KB977453.cab" Source="C:\Temp\Build\MSU Wrapper for SCUP\KB977453.cab" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" ProcessorArchitecture="x64"/>
        </Component>
    </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="MainApplication" Title="Main Application" Level="1">
        <ComponentRef Id="Launch.cmd" />
        <ComponentRef Id="KB977453.cab" />
    </Feature>

    <CustomAction Id="BatchCmd" Property="BatchRun" Value="&quot;[#Launch.cmd]&quot; KB977453" Execute="immediate"/>
    <CustomAction Id="BatchRun" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="check" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
        <Custom Action="BatchCmd" Before="BatchRun">NOT Installed</Custom>
        <Custom Action="BatchRun" After="InstallFiles">NOT Installed</Custom>
        <ScheduleReboot After="InstallFinalize" />
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

</Product>
```

I have x64 release selected in Configuration Manager in Visual Studio. Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

Comment: Hi, not all my code got posted, so here is the first part:  <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" Platform="x64"/>
  <Media Id="1" Cabinet="MSUWrapper.Cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
   <Directory Id="ProgramFiles64Folder">
    <Directory Id="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" Name="Maxwell_KB977453"/>
   </Directory>
  </Directory>

Answer (score 1):

Set DllEntry=**"CAQuietExec64"** for x64 custom actions

http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/qtexec.htm